# Apache wink accessing authentication header in

Tags: java, jax-rs, apache-wink

I am new to Apache Wink. I wanted to know how I can access Basic Authorization header's in my wink server code.
I am using FireFox REST client to access my service.
While authenticating user, i need to pass username and password as Basic Authorization header.

Any idea how i can get the user data in my server side code ?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Using `@HeaderParam`. Example:

```
@GET
public Response myGetMethod(@HeaderParam("BASIC") String basicHeader) {
    ...
}
```

Option 2: Using `HttpHeaders` context. Example:

```
@GET
public Response myGetMethod(@Context HttpHeaders headers) {
    String basicHeader = headers.getRequestHeader("BASIC").get(0);
    ...
}
```

Option 3: You can get the `HttpServletRequest` using `@Context` and get the header from there.